# Cassandra query with multiple OPTIONAL condition

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Is it possible to achieve this kind of query in cassandra efficiently?

Say I have a table something

```
CREATE TABLE something(
    a INT,
    b INT,
    c INT,
    d INT,
    e INT
    PRIMARY KEY(a,b,c,d,e)
);
```

And I want to query this table in following way:
`SELECT * FROM something WHERE a=? AND b=? AND e=?`
or
`SELECT * FROM something WHERE a=? AND c=? AND d=?`
or
`SELECT * FROM something WHERE a=? AND b=? AND d=?`
and so on.

All of the above queries won't work cause cassandra require query to specify clustering column in order.

I know normally this kind of scenario would need to create some materialized view or to denormalize data into several table. However, in this case, I will need to make 4*3*2*1 = **24** tables which is basically not a viable solution.

Secondary index require that `ALLOW FILTERING` option must be turn on for multiple index query to work which seems to be a bad idea. Besides, there may be some high cardinality columns in the something table.

I would like to know if there is any work around to allow such a complicated query to work?

Answer (score 0):

How are you ending up with 24 tables? I did not get this.
If your query has equality condition on 3 columns. Then, isn't it 10 different queries? 5c3.
Maybe I understood your requirement partially and you really need n=(24) queries. But here are my suggestions:

1. Figure out any columns with low cardinality and create a secondary index to satisfy at least 1 query.
2. Things to avoid:
   Don't go with 1 base table and 23 materialized views. Keep this ratio down to 1(base) : 5 or 8(mviews). So it pays to denormalize from application side.
3. You may use uuid as primary key in your base table so you can use them in materialized views.

Overall, even if you have 24 queries, try to get down to 4 or 5 base tables and then create 5 or 6 materialized views on each of them to reach your intended number of 24 or whatever.

Comment: cause its not exactly 3 conditions. I think my question is a little bit of confusing it could be SELECT * FROM something WHERE a=? AND b=?;

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOLR along with Cassandra to get such queries to work with Cassandra. If you are using DSE, it is much more easier. In SOLR query you can directly write:

```
SELECT * FROM keyspace.something WHERE solr_query='a:? b:? e:?'
```

Refer below link which shows you all the possible combinations you can use with SOLR

https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/queriesCql.html?hl=solr%2Cwhere

Answer (score 0):

Writes are very efficient in C*. Also read with partition key is performant.

Create 2 table index and content :

```
CREATE TABLE somethingIndex(
   a_index text PRIMARY KEY,
   a INT
);

CREATE TABLE something(
    a INT PRIMARY KEY,
    b INT,
    c INT,
    d INT,
    e INT
);
```

During write INSERT all combination of (a,b,c,d,e) by concatenating there values.

With 5 element with 3 combination maximum will be 11 insert : 10 INSERT in somethingIndex + 1 INSERT into something.

This will much efficient rather using solr or other solution like materialize view. 
Check solr if you need full text search. For exact search above solution is efficient.

Reading data, first select "a" value from somethingIndex and then read from something table.

```
SELECT a FROM somethingIndex where a_index = ?; // (a+b+e) or (a+c+d) or (a+b+d);

SELECT * FROM something where a = ?;
```

Comment: In my cases, I'll need 24 insertions per creation for something. Won't so many insertions put a lot of stress on something table?